# QGIS: Arrow symbol from 4 raster layers (x y dir)

Tags: qgis, symbology, vector

I have 5m raster layers which represent runoff velocity. They are in 4 separate  layers;

velocity, X-location, Y-location, and Direction.

I want to create an arrow symbol with color according to velocity raster and arrow location and direction from the other 3 layers. How can I do this in Qgis?